Prove the compactness theorem for Radon measures by using Banach-Alaoglu theorem
I was reading the proof of the compactness theorem for Radon measures (Theorem 1.5.15) from Leon Simon's book: Geometric Measure Theory
I was confused by the highlighted part. I hadn't learned the Banach-Alaoglu theorem before, and I found the statement below

$X$ is Banach space. Any closed unit ball in $X^{\star}$ is compact w.r.t. the weak topology.

I'm not sure if it's the right one. If it is, then the Banach space must be $C(K_{j})$. What is the closed unit ball in this situation? and why does the weak compactness in $C(K_{j})^{\star}$ imply the existence of convergent subsequences? Any help will be appreciated.


I feel like the theorem as it is right now is false and $X=$ the Stone-Čech compactification of $\mathbf N$ with $\mu_k=$ the Dirac measure at $k$ for every $k\in\mathbf N$ looks like it should be a counterexample. Is there some metrizability or countability condition that is assumed but not mentionned here?

You're right that the Banach space is $C(K_j)$. The closed unit ball of $C(K_j)^*$ would be a set of the form $\{f \in C(K_j)^* : \|f\| \leq R\}$ for some $R>0$. That is, the ball would be the set of all linear functionals that have norm less than or equal to $R$. Note for fixed $j$ that $F_{j,k}$ are functionals and their norms must be bounded in $k$ by the assumptions of the theorem (namely $\sup_k \mu_k(K_j) < \infty$). This implies that they are in a closed, ball in the dual space. The author is using sequential compactness here. For separable Banach spaces, the closed ball is also sequentially compact in the dual space. Thus any bounded sequence in the dual space has a convergent subsequence.

Why the norm of $F_{j,k}$ is bounded? $|F_{j,k}(f)|\leq \sup f \times\mu_{k}(K_{j})$, what if $\sup f$ is not uniform bounded?

@OneLamp It is an operator norm. Since the norm on $C(K_j)$ is $|f|{C(K_j)}= \sup{x\in K_j} |f(x_j)|$ then we  have $|F_{j,k}(f)| \leq |f|{C(K_j)} \times \mu_k(K_j)$. Thus $|F{j,k}| \leq \mu_k(K_j)$.
